# Nginx forward for hostname

Tags: nginx

I have an NGINX as reverse proxy with PHP-fpm. Nginx is set up for serving www.somehost.com. I added another host www.anotherhost.com. Now I need to setup redirect in this way: If user type www.anotherhost.com then it redirects to www.somehost.com/someurl, but url in browser bar shouldn't change. If I set up rewrite it works, but it rewrites url in browser too. Is it possoble ro redirect in this way?

```
if ($host = "www.anotherhost.com") {
   rewrite ^ http://www.somehost.com/someurl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up another virtual host for `www.anotherhost.com` in your configuration, where you set up `root` directive so that it is the subdirectory where `www.somehost.com/someurl` is.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name www.somehost.com;
    root /var/www/www.somehost.com;

    ... FastCGI config ...
}

server {
    server_name www.anotherhost.com;
    root /var/www/www.somehost.com/someurl;

    ... FastCGI config ...
}
```

You need to include also other `server` block directives like `listen`.

In nginx, one should not use `if` for matching virtual hosts. One should always use separate virtual hosts.

Comment: What if *someurl* formes dynamically and physically doesn't exists?

Comment: Then you just configure the front-controller pattern in the `www.anotherhost.com` configuration.

Comment: Have you any thougths how to do it?

Comment: No, since there isn't enough information on the subject in your question.